# Can't acces my site and without login and drush clear cache

Tags: drush, caching, staging

I moved my local site to shared host.

- all code has been deployed to the staging server
- I changed settings.php
- import the database from local to the staging server database

When I try to reach the site I get an `HTTP ERROR 500`. In phpMyAdmin I TRUNCATE the cache tables:

```
TRUNCATE cache_config;
TRUNCATE cache_container;
TRUNCATE cache_data;
TRUNCATE cache_default;
TRUNCATE cache_discovery;
TRUNCATE cache_dynamic_page_cache;
TRUNCATE cache_entity;
TRUNCATE cache_menu;
TRUNCATE cache_render;
TRUNCATE cache_toolbar;
```

If I look in the error logs I see:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Drupal\\Core\\Cache\\DatabaseBackend' not found in /home/mysite.nl/public_html/staging/index.php on line 16\n'
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: I think I understand what is causing the problem - a missing DB driver for PHP. However, before "officially" posting my answer I would like some more information. What version of Drush (and Drupal)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `$settings['hash_salt'] = '';`. I changed this to `$settings['hash_salt'] = 'CHANGE THIS';` after this I could reach the site!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database connection to the DB server is correct. I was using an older local password for DB which caused a similar issue when moving to live hosting.